# Optimize Update Join between two large tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have an update that does this:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.X=T2.Y
Set T1.A=T2.B;
```

Table1 is around 10,000,000 records
Table2 is around 40,000 records
I have an index on both T1.X and T2.Y

Naturally this takes forever. Is there a way to reduce the time?

For instance, my understanding the join is not the sum of the table records but the product. Is there a way (if this is true) to step through the join 1000 Table1 records at at time?

Comment: 10 million records is not very much for mysql.Do you have the join fields indexed?

Comment: If you have indexes, then MySQL should not be using a nested loops join.

Comment: This is about as efficient as it gets. Can you upgrade your hardware?

Comment: How many rows are being updated?  Even 40,000 rows takes time, but you could be updating every row in `table1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table1 which is several million rows is being updated. The On statement fields are both indexed in their respective tables, not sure if the Set fields are but didn't think that was relevant. Since both tables have many other fields is there anything/way to just loading the fields that are relevant here or does the statement itself handle that?

Comment: @Mihai The two On fields in the respective tables are indeed indexed.

Comment: @user3649739 . . . There can be multiple matches between the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is only one match inside Table2 for any given Table1. However more than one Table1 can find matches inside Table2. So where Table1 might be (A,B,C,B,B,A,D) Table2 is only (A,B,C,D)

Comment: Add a `WHERE T1.A!=T2.B` condition

Comment: The JOIN condition is on different columns,I`m guessing this WHERE might cut down the number of rows to UPDATE if not all rows need to be updated.

Comment: @Mihai I'm not sure how adding a where for A!=B when my condition is A=B would help?

Comment: @Mihai The thing is all of the rows in Table1 need to be updated.  Table1 includes mutliple records each one of which has a field that corresponds to a singular record in Table2

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Join works on both full tables. SO I modified my query to this:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join (Select T2.Y,T2.B from Table2) as T2
On T1.X=T2.Y
Set T1.A=T2.B;
```

I haven't run the entire query again but when I limited it as a test to 'where T1.ID<100' it reduced from 18+ seconds to 1 second when I add the Select statement i.

UPDATE
I also tested pushing in a limited # of records at a time. Interstingly enough 10 records takes 1 second, 1000 records takes 6 seconds and 10000 take 250 seconds.  So I am going to test nesting this in a while to step through 1000 records at a time.

Comment: Subquery is the same thing as a JOIN. You've done nothing to optimize it writing it that way. Now someone will come along and think that using subqueries is faster than JOIN-ing tables. The reason it's faster is because you're reducing your data to lesser amount because you have `WHERE T1.ID < 100`. Real reason why this is slow is because you're issuing too many I/O operations. Do you have a mechanical hard disk?

Comment: @Mjh No sir, it is not the ID<. If I try it with <100 w/o the select it takes 10x longer than with.  That said it is running off a hosted server. Are you saying there is a way to run this off RAM somehow? Even "optimized" this updates only 100 records per second which is 10x too slow.

Comment: @Mjh Just as a test I ran 10 tests, 5 with random 100 record ranges w/o the Select, 5 random 100 record ranges with, the difference in speed is near 10x in all cases.

Comment: MySQL is ACID compliant (InnoDB to be more precise), which means it forces hard drive to actually write the data before reporting back to you that data is written. Therefore, no, you can't perform this in RAM. Technically, it does get performed in RAM first but the reason for being slow is because HDD is doing a lot of work. Reason for the disk doing a lot of work is because it's limited with I/O capability or bandwith. If you reduce the amount it works, of course the query is faster. Now, I am still not wrong - your query IS NOT faster because of a subquery. It's misleading.

Comment: @Mjh I am sorry how is the subquery not faster? In all tests I kept it at ID<100 in order to not process all 10,000,000 records and have a more reasonable test. In all tests it ran 10x faster with the subquery than without. I'm happy to paste the screenshots of each pass if you like.

Comment: There are 2 things you must be aware of. A subquery is exactly the same thing as a JOIN. There are literally no differences between them. The second thing is that MySQL will **not** write to the disk if the data didn't actually change. Before writing, it will check if written value equals to what you told it to update. If it's the same, no write happens. So, if you ran a "normal" query first and altered the data, then you ran a subquery where MySQL doesn't do anything to the disk - yes, it will appear faster, because 2nd query won't issue any I/O operations.

Answer (score 0):

It does not answer your question, but here is a way to use your logic to make it faster:

UPDATE table_A a
INNER JOIN (SELECT TRUNCATE(lat,3) AS lat, TRUNCATE(lon,3) AS lon, `address` FROM table_B) b
SET a.`address` = b.`address`
WHERE TRUNCATE(a.lat,3) = b.lat AND TRUNCATE(a.lon,3) = b.lon AND a.`address` IS NULL;

When tou need to make a work on your data to use it, instead of transform them in the 'Where', transform them when you take them aou of your table.